# Join regresa registros duplicados mysql codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

Estoy realizando una coansulta a 3 tablas que tiene un  id en comun,  pero  esta me devuelve registros duplicados  2 veces  cada uno de ellos

```
    public function select_informacion_encargados(){
        $this->db->select('encargado.nombre, encargado.materno, encargado.paterno,email.email, telefono.telefono, prestadores_servicios.cargo_encargado');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->join("email","email.id_servicios  = prestadores_servicios.id_servicios");
        $this->db->join("telefono","telefono.id_servicios  = prestadores_servicios.id_servicios");
        $this->db->join("encargado","encargado.id_servicios  = prestadores_servicios.id_servicios");
        $this->db->where("prestadores_servicios.id_servicios", 2);
        $result = $this->db->get()->result();

        return $result;
    }
```

Como podria  ahcer para que no me  duplique los registros

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer un distinct antes del select.

```
public function select_informacion_encargados(){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('encargado.nombre, encargado.materno, encargado.paterno,email.email, telefono.telefono, prestadores_servicios.cargo_encargado');
    ....
}
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656622/codeigniter-how-to-do-a-select-distinct-fieldname-mysql-query)